# how to get result from promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have Promise and do not know how to get string "foo" from it. May be my Promise is incorrect.

```
const bar = new Promise((res, rej) => res("foo"));
then((result) => {
  return result;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you should do it :

```
const bar = new Promise((res, rej) => res("foo"));

bar.then((result) => {
     console.log(result);
    // do whatever you want to do with result
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

the `then` handler is called when the promise is resolved.
The `catch`  handler is called when the promise is rejected.

Comment: Can you assume the promise will resolve instantly (like a normal function) and attempt to obtain the result, something like `bar.result`, be it "foo" or undefined (for when it didn't resolve yet)?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const bar = new Promise((res) => res("foo"))
.then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
});
```

You need a period (`.`) before the word `then` -> `.then`

`then` is a method of `Promise`, therefore you need `.then` to call the method. `then` **is not** a global function that stand by itself.

---

When you do:

```js
new Promise((res) => res("foo")).then((result) => ...
```

any `then` will only fire when the *Promise* is resolved.

The *Promise* register all the `then` methods internally and call them when you do `res("foo")` (in your case), so this is why you need a `.then` - to register those callbacks to be called when/if the promise is *resolved*

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the Promise to the variable `bar`. If you want the value you should `then` the Promise like the following:

```js
const bar = new Promise((res, rej) => res("foo")).then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
});
```

It's a good practice also to add a `catch` statement to handle errors.

Finally, if you're new to Promises there is [this free course](https://www.udacity.com/course/javascript-promises--ud898) on Udacity offered by Google which will help you understand Promises better.